# Removing Background Around Contour

Tags: python, opencv, mask, contour

I am only a couple weeks into learning coding with Python and OpenCV, but StackOverflow has helped me numerous times. However I cant seem to figure this issue out so decided to ask my first question.

- I am trying to take an image
- Find the largest contour by area
- Remove the background **outside** the contour
- Effectively removing the background from the largest "object" in the
  picture.

I am struggling with the last part. I know I need to create a mask somehow then place the mask over the original image.

How do I create the correct type of mask? And how do I place the mask on top of the original image?

[image: Image Being Used]

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
image = cv2.imread('Resources/X.png')

# Grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Find Canny edges
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)

# Finding Contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged,
                                       cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cv2.imshow('Canny Edges After Contouring', edged)
print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(contours)))
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Largest contour
c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)


# Not sure what to do from here. Attempt below:
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)                  # What is this actually doing? what does np.unit8 mean?
cv2.drawContours(mask, c, -1, (255, 255, 255), 1)       # I am drawing the correct outline/contour

cv2.imshow('Mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Chris

EDIT:

I managed to do it but not exactly sure what I am doing :-(
How would I get a different color background? I presume I have to fill the blank_mask with another color?
Also not sure what the bitwise function is actually doing.

```
blank_mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.fillPoly(blank_mask, [c], (255,255,255))
blank_mask = cv2.cvtColor(blank_mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(original,original,mask=blank_mask)
cv2.imshow('Result', result)
```

Comment: Post your input image to some free hosting service and put the URL here

Comment: Hi fmw42. I edited my original post with a link to the image. I actually managed to figure it out and get a result. However I cant say I really know whats going on. I have added some questions on the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to change the background on your image using Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input and get its dimensions
- Threshold on black and invert to get white on black background
- Get the largest contour from the inverted threshold image
- Draw the largest contour as white filled on a black background as a mask
- Create an inverted mask
- Create a new colored background image
- Apply the mask to the image
- Apply the inverted mask to the background color image
- Add the two images
- Save the result

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('shapes.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# threshold on black
# Define lower and uppper limits of what we call "white-ish"
lower = np.array([0, 0, 0])
upper = np.array([0, 0, 0])

# Create mask to only select black
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# invert mask so shapes are white on black background
thresh_inv = 255 - thresh

# get the largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh_inv, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw white contour on black background as mask
mask = np.zeros((hh,ww), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [big_contour], 0, (255,255,255), cv2.FILLED)

# invert mask so shapes are white on black background
mask_inv = 255 - mask

# create new (blue) background
bckgnd = np.full_like(img, (255,0,0))

# apply mask to image
image_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

# apply inverse mask to background
bckgnd_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(bckgnd, bckgnd, mask=mask_inv)

# add together
result = cv2.add(image_masked, bckgnd_masked)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('shapes_inverted_mask.jpg', mask_inv)
cv2.imwrite('shapes_masked.jpg', image_masked)
cv2.imwrite('shapes_bckgrnd_masked.jpg', bckgnd_masked )
cv2.imwrite('shapes_result.jpg', result)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('image_masked', image_masked)
cv2.imshow('bckgrnd_masked', bckgnd_masked)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Mask image from largest contour:

[image]

Image masked:

[image]

Background masked:

[image]

Result:

[image]